# how to add query string parameters in ElasticSearch DeleteByQuery java API?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin, elasticsearch-java-api

I am using Elasticsearch version 2.3.1

I have installed deletebyquery plugin to delete documents, And using java API to delete.

here is my java api request

```
DeleteByQueryRequestBuilder deleteRequest = DeleteByQueryRequestBuilder(esType, DeleteByQueryAction.INSTANCE)
        .setIndices(index)
        .setTypes(type);
deleteRequest.setQuery(boolQuery);
DeleteByQueryResponse resp = deleteRequest.get();
```

My question is , How to add the query string parameters such as **size , routing** in Deletebyquery query request in java? these params are mentioned in doc(https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/2.3/delete-by-query-usage.html) but do not know how to add in java api!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
deleteRequest.setRouting(routing) // to set routing
deleteRequest.request().size(size) // to set the size
```